# UIButton under UIView should NOT be clickable

Tags: iphone, uiview, uibutton

I have a view with some UIButtons on it. I add another - semi transparent - view on top of all, displaying some information to the user (actually, it's kind of a selfmade modal-alert). But the buttons under the semi-transparent view still react to taps. They shouldn't, though.

How can I prevent the buttons from reacting to taps?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Setting,

```
semiTransparentViewOnTopOfAll.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

should solve this problem. But, still if the problem persists, try,

```
semiTransparentViewOnTopOfAll.exclusiveTouch = YES;
```

Comment: thank you thank you thank you. I spent days and all I had to do was add these two lines. God bless you man

Answer (score 1):

do like this

```
button.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
```

by getting all buttons from view